# Retain checkbox state

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have used the following code to retain the selection of a dropdown menu upon the refresh of a page.

```
$("#form_Selection > option").each(function() {
    if (this.value == 'variable') { 
        this.selected=true; 
    }
});
```

I am having a hard time configuring similar code that will retain the state of a checkbox after a refresh.  Any ideas?

Comment: For the menu, isn't `$(#form_Selection).val(variable)` simpler?

Comment: The way I have done this in PHP is to save all of my options in an array, and if it is selected (in a $_GET or $_POST variable) I put that option on top, because the first option appears in the select box.

Comment: Further on that, I would probably save the value as a SESSION variable with ajax, and unset the session variables after the form has been submitted (if you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
   {if (this.value == 'variable') {this.checked="checked";}}
```

Comment: The `checked` property is a boolean not a string.

Answer (score 1):

How would the following work (I've not re-printed the logic part of your code, just setting the checkbox
    `$(this).attr('checked', true);`

Comment: You should actually be using .prop instead of .attr, as outlined by @AlexStack below.

Answer (score 0):

For saving the state of all checkboxes using [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) and [prop('checked')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript), you can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage):

```
$(':checkbox').each(function(index,element){
    //save the 'checked' property of every checkbox
    if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
        sessionStorage['checked-checkboxes']=sessionStorage['checked-checkboxes'] + ',';
    }
}
```

And then when the page is loaded:

```
var checkedCheckboxes = sessionStorage['checked-checkboxes'];
//if there's anything saved in the sessionStorage for checked checkboxes
if ( checkedCheckboxes ) {
    var checkedCheckboxesNames = checkedCheckboxes.split(',');
    for( var i=0; i < checkedCheckboxesNames; i++ ) {
        $( '#' + checkedCheckboxesNames[i] ).prop( 'checked', true );
    }
}
```

The idea is simple: when saving, save the id of all the checkboxes which are saved, and when loading, get all those ids and set the checkboxes.

Of course you can replace `sessionStorage` with `localStorage` if you want permanent storage. Please note that:

- all checkboxes must have an id to be identified with this algorithm.
- there shouldn't be any other variable in the storage that uses the same key (a prefix can be used to eliminate side effects).

I hope it helps :)